# How to set height and width to MPAndroidChart BarChart?

Tags: android, height, width, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am trying to add a static BarChart to the activity, but its covering whole screen. The code i am using is below -

MainActivity.java

```
 BarChart bc = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);


    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 1));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(12f, 3));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(18f, 4));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(9f, 5));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(12f, 6));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(10f, 7));

    BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");

    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("January");
    labels.add("February");
    labels.add("March");
    labels.add("April");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("June");
    labels.add("July");
    labels.add("August");
bc=new BarChart(this);

    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);


    setContentView(bc);

   bc.setData(data);
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp">

    </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart>
```

Where i am going wrong?
Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `setContentView()` the layout parameters of the specified view are ignored, and set to the default `MATCH_PARENT`, so in your code `setContentView(bc)` will cause your BarChart to fill the entire screen.

One solution would be to place your static BarChart view under a ViewGroup, like `LinearLayout`, in activity_main.xml, and call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

EDIT:

Another thing, in your code you obtained the BarChart defined in your xml by doing:

```
BarChart bc = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
```

Which is correct... but later on in your code, you made the above line pointless by assigning `bc`to another BarChart you instantiated:

```
bc=new BarChart(this);
```

So, remove this line and you should be able to see your BarChart.

Comment: I am already using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
also made changes in xml, added chart into `LinearLayout`, the other `setContentView(bc);` is for setting chart content, your method is not working, chart not displaying.

Comment: Got this error when I removed `bc=new BarChart(this);` **java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**

After that I introduced new Barchart
`BarChart abc;
Bc.addView(abc = new BarChart(MainActivity.this));
abc.setData(data);`

Worked well for me.

Comment: Sounds to me like you were still doing `setContentView(bc)`. Glad it worked out for you in the end :)

Comment: no I am not using `setContentView(bc)` using `addView()`. Yes its working but I don't know its the right procedure or not.